# Как обработать исключение reflect.InvocationTargetException?

Tags: java, android

При попытке вызвать search при незаполненных полях EditText, программа вылетает с ошибкой `Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.
При попытке обработать эту ошибку в catch, студия пишет, что эту ошибку нельзя обработать в try-catch, поскольку она к ней не относится. Это, конечно, правильно, так и есть, но как же всё-таки можно её перехватить при незаполненных EditText и написать юзеру типа "поля то заполни!"?

Вот для наглядности кусок кода:

```java
public void search (View view) {

        String value = edit.getText().toString();
        letters = Integer.parseInt(value);
        String value2 = editTextQplace1.getText().toString();
        mesto1in = Integer.parseInt(value2);

......
}
```

Полный текст ошибки:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.golgofa.wordfinder, PID: 26849
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at ru.golgofa.wordfinder.MainActivity.search(MainActivity.java:87)
```

Comment: Приведите полный лог ошибки. Кажется у просто NPE

Comment: Добавила. 86-87 строки - String value = edit.getText().toString();
        letters = Integer.parseInt(value); edit.getText() как раз editText пустой

Comment: вы что передаете пустой стринг - `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`?

Comment: Ну конечно же он пустой - поле то EditText юзер не заполнил. Но NumberFormatException легко перехватить в try, а вот reflect.InvocationTargetException, которая появляется раньше неё никак перехватить не умею.

Comment: По идее вы как минимум можете проверять строки на пустоту и выводить ошибку. Типа так: `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || TextUtils.isEmpty(value2)) { /*todo Вывести ошибку*/ } else {/*Тут ваш код парсинга строк*/}`. А вообще отлов `NumberFormatException` вполне должен работать.

Comment: Да. Это сработало. Спасибо!